# How to partition a single Neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j

Can one Neo4j database be divided up so that there are multiple starting points in one database so that all queries can be isolated, instead of having multiple databases?

I have thought about this and I think it can work up to a point, but once things like labels are used then the idea will not work, as a label query will always span the whole database.

Anyway I would like to know if anyone has successfully done this and how they did it.

Comment: Have you tried to use a WHERE clause for this? E.g. using the Movie dataset something like this `MATCH (people:Person)-[relatedTo]-(movie:Movie) WHERE people.name in ["Tom Hanks", "Keanu Reeves"] RETURN people.name, Type(relatedTo), relatedTo`

Comment: Yes, I tried a WHERE clause, but I used people.db_type = 'schema_id_323' in all the queries. But it got very cumbersome for the devleoper, adding a property to every item in the where clause. I thought using START would be good as it can be added to the beginning of every query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like multitenancy. Neo4j 2.0.1 does not at this time support multitenancy as a feature. There are various methods and strategies for implementing a multitenant architecture within your Neo4j database instance.

You can partition sets of your property graph by label. Since nodes can have multiple labels, you can label one partition with a unique identifying label for that partition.

Please refer to documentation on labels here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html

Things to note with this strategy are to ensure that all your Cypher calls contain the partition identifier for the label, to ensure that the two partitions are isolated from one another within the graph. It's important to ensure that relationships from one partition do not span into another partition.

For example, partition 1 could be the label `Partition1`. Assuming your application context is operating on `Partition1`:

```
MERGE (user:User:Partition1 { name: 'Peter' })
RETURN user
```

Assuming your application context is operating on `Partition2`:

```
MERGE (user:User:Partition2 { name: 'Peter' })
RETURN user
```

When executing these two queries, two separate Peters are created for `Partition1` and `Partition2`.

You'll just need to ensure that the partition label your application is operating on appends its label to each one of your queries. While this is tedious, it is the suggested way to go about multitenancy at this time.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable way to do it. Is there any way to make every query automatically add the :Partion2 qulaifier for the relvant partition without specifying it in the Cypher?

Comment: In code this shouldn't be too hard to implement. Write a class that takes a tenancy context that runs on top of your Cypher queries and injects the partition label everywhere it matches on an arbitrary label.

Comment: A tenancy context? I had not even heard of this. I will research this and try it. By the way, I am accessing Neo4j via Clojure and the Neocons library, so I will need to dive a bit deeper than the Java APi

Comment: By tenancy context I mean the context of the tenant, i.e. your partition :)

Comment: How do you set the label names dynamically? E.g. PartitionXYZ